# Draw a line over a node Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, draw, line

Can someone help me to draw a red line --- like in the photo?
Thank you so much in advanced.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=4cm,minimum width=7cm,text width = 5cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{qStqsfate-spqsface mqsdfodel}] (A)
  {Tranqsdfqsiqsftion \\
  $ \tilde{y}_{t/t-1} = g \big( \tilde{y}_{t-1} ; u_t ; \omega_t \big) $ \\
  $ \downarrow $ \\
  Measurement\\
  $ \tilde{z}_{t/t-1} = f \big( \tilde{y}_{t-1} ; u_t ; \omega_t \big) $  };
\node[xshift=8cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=4cm,minimum width=7cm,text width=5cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{Estqsdfqsimateqsdfd daqsdfqsdta \; \; \; Empiriqsdfqsdfcal daqsdfqdsfta}] (B)
  {$ \; \; \tilde{y}_{t} \rightarrow \emptyset $ \\
  \vspace{5mm}
  $  \tilde{z}_{t/t-1} \rightarrow z_t $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-4.5cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,text width=4cm,align=center,label={[name=kalman]above:\textbf{Kqsdfqalmqsdfqan fqsdfqsdiltqsdfqser}}] (C)
  {$ v_t = y_t - y_{t,t-1} $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-6.5cm,draw,fill=white,rectangle,minimum height=1.2cm,text width=1.5cm,align=center] (D)
  {$ y_t $};  

\draw [->] (A) to (kalman);
\draw [->] (B) to (kalman);
\draw [->] (C) to (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 8):

Is this what you are looking for?

The node in question already has the name `(B)`, therefore you simply want to draw a line from `(B.south)` to `(B.north)`. To extend these coordinates slightly use `yshift` within the coordinates like so: `([yshift=-0.5cm]B.south)` and `([yshift=0.5cm]B.north)`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=4cm,minimum width=7cm,text width = 5cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{State-space model}] (A)
  {Transition \\
  $ \tilde{y}_{t/t-1} = g \big( \tilde{y}_{t-1} ; u_t ; \omega_t \big) $ \\
  $ \downarrow $ \\
  Measurement\\
  $ \tilde{z}_{t/t-1} = f \big( \tilde{y}_{t-1} ; u_t ; \omega_t \big) $  };
\node[xshift=8cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,minimum height=4cm,minimum width=7cm,text width=5cm,align=center,label=above:\textbf{Estimated data \; \; \; Empirical data}] (B)
  {$ \; \; \tilde{y}_{t} \rightarrow \emptyset $ \\
  \vspace{5mm}
  $  \tilde{z}_{t/t-1} \rightarrow z_t $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-4.5cm,draw,fill=white,ellipse,text width=4cm,align=center,label={[name=kalman]above:\textbf{Kalman filter}}] (C)
  {$ v_t = y_t - y_{t,t-1} $};
\node[xshift=4cm,yshift=-6.5cm,draw,fill=white,rectangle,minimum height=1.2cm,text width=1.5cm,align=center] (D)
  {$ y_t $};  

\draw [red,dashed] ([yshift=-0.5cm]B.south)--([yshift=0.5cm]B.north); %<---- added

\draw [->] (A) to (kalman);
\draw [->] (B) to (kalman);
\draw [->] (C) to (D);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want the red line to shift to the right a little bit. (that divises the arrows). Could you do that ?

Comment: Use `\draw [red,dashed] ([yshift=-0.5cm,xshift=0.1cm]B.south)--([yshift=0.5cm,xshift=0.1cm]B.north);` Adjust the `xshift` as you see fit.

Answer (score 2):

the same approach as at [Milo](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/128068/milo) answer, however with some effort to make image code concise and shorter:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, positioning, shapes}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 8mm and 4mm,
E/.style args = {#1/#2}{ellipse, draw, minimum height=#1,
            text width=#2, align=center},
   E/.default = 4cm/5cm
                        ]
\node[E, label=above:\textbf{State-space model}] (A)
        {Transition \\
        $\tilde{y}_{t/t-1} = g \big( \tilde{y}_{t-1} ; u_t ; \omega_t \big) $ \\
        $ \downarrow $ \\
        Measurement\\
        $ \tilde{z}_{t/t-1} = f \big( \tilde{y}_{t-1} ; u_t ; \omega_t \big) $
        };
\node[E, label=above:\textbf{Estimated data \quad Empirical data},
      right=of A] (B)
        {$\begin{aligned}
            \tilde{y}_{t}       & \rightarrow \emptyset\\[5mm]
            \tilde{z}_{t/t-1}   & \rightarrow z_{t\hphantom{/t-1}} % <---
         \end{aligned}$
         };
\node[E=2em/3cm,
      label={[name=kalman]above:\textbf{Kalman filter}},
      below=of $(A.south)!0.5!(B.south)$ ] (C)
        {$ v_t = y_t - y_{t,t-1} $};
\node[draw, minimum height=1.2cm, minimum width=1.5cm,
      below=of C] (D)
        {$ y_t $};
%
\draw[->]   (A) edge (kalman)
            (B) edge (kalman)
            (C)  to  (D);
% line through ellipse B
\draw[thick, dashed, red]   ([yshift=3mm] B.north) -- ([yshift=-3mm] B.south);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

- for positioning of nodes are used  `tikz` library`positioning and`calc`
- for ellipses is defined common style
- equation in eliipse "B" use `aligned` environment defined  in the package `amsmath`

*note:* please always code snippet extent to complete but small document. it is more easy to help ypu if we see preamble with (only  relevant) information about your image.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. But I want the red line to shift to the right a little bit. (that divises the arrows). Could you do that ?

Comment: @DgPHAM, :-) :-). i made some effort to now so this. now i push equation slightly to left by adding  `\hspace{3.5ex}` on the end of last line of equation int ellipse B. is now better?

Comment: @DgPHAM, beter solution is use `hphantom{/t-1}` by which the right side of equation becomes as wide as the left side. see edited answer.